# Is it possible for someone to get a list of all the files in Apache's www folder without FTP?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a 2.5GB file that I want to allow users to download after they buy it. I originally planned on hiding the file and then just using readfile to dump the file's contents with .zip headers but my GoDaddy server apparently won't allow me to use readfile on such a large file, so I'm stuck with changing the name of this important file every hour. But if someone can just list all the files on my www folder anyway then people can take it without paying for it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there's an index.html file in this folder, then it's not possible for them to do that. But if it just contains files, then you can [use .htaccess](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=prevent+listing+of+Apache+directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't allow indexing of the directory then they can't obtain a file listing. To do that create a .htaccess file in the directory and add:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Alternatively, if the folder has an index page this will also prevent the server disclosing a directory listing and instead serve the index page.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than 5 gig host so use the php `exec` command to copy your file with another name

let say you keep your file with a unguessable name in a unguessable folder 
so whenever the buyer confirm the order then you copy the file to a known folder with user-generated name, then pass the link to user

if your host is linux then use `cp` command if it's windows use `copy`

use something like `cp oldname.ext newname.ext` or `copy oldname.ext newname.ext`
after a certain time you will delete the file in the known folder

Comment: indexing is not the solution, what if a customer buy a product and share the download link with others? then all the time the download address will be same and others can download the file without buying it

Comment: What other choice do I have? My host won't let me output a file as large as what my file is. As is, I have a cronjob that changes the filename of the important file every hour.

Comment: did you see the host let you use `exec` or `system` or `cmdshell` command?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I use exec exactly?

Comment: you can use it like `exec('command',$arr);` in the command part write the "copy and rename" command as i typed in main answer check following link : http://us1.php.net/function.exec